# muti-tenancy, regional residency and regional faili-over in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito, automatic-failover

For architecting a multi-tenant SAAS serverless application on AWS, This is how we plan to manage "users" and multi-tenancy. A relevant blog post here: https://medium.com/@tarekbecker/serverless-enterprise-grade-multi-tenancy-using-aws-76ff5f4d0a23

In order to ensure business continuity, we would also like to ensure

1. Regional failover
2. Data residency for personally identifiable information
3. Disaster recovery

What changes should be made in the following architecture in order to integrate these aspects into the serverless application?

[image]

Comment: All the resources that you have are regional. For automated failover usually you would add R53 to evaluate health of your API gateway and failover to different region.

Comment: @Marcin DynamoDB happens to be a global resource I think. How does deployment work for duplicate services in other regions? For ex: Cognito pool. How would that be duplicated and deployed in other regions?

Comment: DdB is regional, unless you enable global tables. Sadly, don't know about congito. I guess each region would have to its own pool.